# irregular characters with the pattern 86/88 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Following pattern is to be print in the 86/88 assembly language but some irrelevant characters are also printing.
[Here Is The Pattern To Be Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvx3O.png)
[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf44c.jpg)

The pattern is print by incrementing the columns and decrementing the rows in each iteration using the nested loops.

```
 .MODEL SMALL
 .STACK 64
 .DATA
 .CODE
 MAIN PROC FAR
 
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX
 
    MOV CX,5
 ;ROW 5 AND COLUMN 15
 
    MOV DH,5
    MOV DL,15
    MOV BX,'1'
 
 OUTERLOOP:
    PUSH CX
    PUSH BX
 
    MOV BH,00
    MOV AH,2
    INT 21H
 
    DEC DH
    INC DL
    INT 10H
 ;INCREMENTING COLUMNS AND DECREMENTING ROWS
 
    PUSH DX
 INNERLOOP:
 
    MOV DX,BX
    MOV AH,02
    INT 21H
    INC BXf
    LOOP INNERLOOP
    POP DX
 
    POP BX
    POP CX
    INC BX
    LOOP OUTERLOOP
```

Answer (score 3):

At `OUTERLOOP:` you are invoking DOS function [INT 21H/AH=2](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm) which writes the character from `DL` at current cursor position. `DL` is initialized with value `15` (control character SI), definitely not what you wanted.

Get rid of `INT 21H` in `OUTERLOOP:`.

You should comment each DOS/BIOS interrupt with their intended purpose when you want others to quickly understand your program.
If your emulator doesn't support debugging, you can compile the program to MZ executable file and step through each instruction with Turbo Debugger in DosBox.